# 'QRadioButton' size problem when I set size to Qradiobutton

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I use this code to set QRadiobutton size and When I set the size to big size I get pixelated circle like in the image:

[image]

Even if I set the size of th button to a small size I get also a pixelated circle

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 600, 700)
        self.q = QRadioButton('click', self)
        self.q.move(20, 20)
        self.q.setStyleSheet('QRadioButton::indicator { width: 50px; height: 50px;}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    d = main()
    d.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? Because on that platform Qt uses pixmaps to draw controls, and they can get very ugly if you set a very big size.

Comment: yes I use windows... Is there is another soultion to create big QRadioButtons ?

Comment: Add the line `app.setStyle('fusion')` after the line `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)`.

Comment: it worked thnx a lot